# when ran react-native run-android it gives an error Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: android, react-native

I am new to react native after developing some features I tried to update react native version using git update process from then i am facing this error. I have gone through similar questions that are available but none of the solutions gave any positive results. any help would be appreciated. here I attach manifest file too. The errors are pointing to my project name which has '-' in it.

```
Scanning 668 folders for symlinks in /home/administrator/x-mobile/node_modules (3ms)
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
useNewCruncher has been deprecated. It will be removed in a future version of the gradle plugin. New cruncher is now always enabled.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFbuiTextlayoutbuilderTextlayoutbuilder100Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoDrawee130Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFbcore130Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFresco130Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipeline130Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineBase130Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineOkhttp3130Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookReactReactNative0484Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookSoloaderSoloader010Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets SKIPPED
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
/home/administrator/ncstrax-mobile/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:2: AAPT: Tag <manifest> attribute package has invalid character '-'.

/home/administrator/ncstrax-mobile/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:18: AAPT: Tag <application> attribute name has invalid character '-'.

/home/administrator/x-mobile/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:24: AAPT: Tag <activity> attribute name has invalid character '-'.

/home/administrator/x-mobile/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:2: Tag <manifest> attribute package has invalid character '-'.
/home/administrator/x-mobile/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:18: Tag <application> attribute name has invalid character '-'.
/home/administrator/x-mobile/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:24: Tag <activity> attribute name has invalid character '-'.

:app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.99 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.x-mobile"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    <android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.x-mobile.MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.x-mobile.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml? There seems to be something wrong with it.

Comment: What's the name of your project? I bet it's named with a '-' and the AndroidManifest.xml is throwing errors

Comment: it was never a problem for me earlier I did some updates to my project like react native version from then I am seeing these errors @MattyK14

Comment: added manifest file @NimrodArgov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And although the application ID looks like a traditional Java package
>   name, the naming rules for the application ID are a bit more
>   restrictive:
>
> It must have at least two segments (one or more dots). Each segment
>   must start with a letter. All characters must be alphanumeric or an
>   underscore [a-zA-Z0-9_].

No "-" allowed in your application id: `com.x-mobile.MainApplication`

[For reference](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html)

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer might seem weird, but I think you should navigate to this very path '/home/administrator/ncstrax-mobile/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug' in your PC and make sure the folder is kept open before you run 'react-native run-android'. Give it a try, I hope it helps resolve this issue.

Comment: I did followed your instructions, but no luck